# UV pie menu, need help with rip command (two functions in one)

Tags: python, scripting, uv, pie-menu

I recently made a pie menu for the uv editor to speed things up. It's activated by clicking on the RMB. One of the command "rip faces" doesnt work the way i want to at the moment, here is what i need help with. When you select the rip faces command in the pie menu you still have to press "g" in order to move the ripped face, this is a little backwards since the whole idea with the pie menu is to not have to use the keyboard at all.

Is there any way you can have "two commands on one button"? (rip + "g") 
If some on e could provide me with the code for this it would be great.

Here is a link to the script: http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.se/2015/04/addon-jimmy-pie-uv.html